Proportion as an outcome measure in athe synthetic control model
I am currently conducting a study on the rate of deaths by suicide before and after a a particular policy implementation. The big problem is that my test case (New Jersey) perennially has the lowest death by suicide rate in the country.  I have seen that the rate of overall deaths by suicide per 100k, and the rate of financially motivated deaths by suicide per 100k both show comparatively low rates against the donor states. However, if I look at financially motivated deaths by suicide as proportion of all deaths by suicide, the numbers become more comparable (though admittedly much more volatile). My question is whether it is appropriate to used this proportion as the dependent variable in the models or whether it should really just be the rate of either outcome in the population. I haven't been able to find any similar approaches in the existing literature.
The study hypothesizes that the policy change would result in an increase in the rate of death by suicide relative to the controls but with rates in the test case being so low, it's hard to get the donor pool to match in the pretreatment period.
I am using the MSCMT package in R
